# How to move flash video window to the primary display?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, flash, window, fullscreen

How can I move my flashplayer video (fullscreen) to my primary monitor? I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 and two displays.

Didn't find anything with Google. If you need more info let me know.

Comment: If you move your browser's window to the primary monitor, the fullscreen video window should be displayed on that monitor.

Comment: I think that won't work for flash, lgarzo. There was a hack once, but I wouldn't do that. If you are using Chromium/Chrome and are talking mostly about Youtube, I recommend https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdnjdibmddfgbdohgacjakddhncfhpcf

Comment: lgarzo: this is not working for me. @user42257 its working great on youtube but not for other sites e.g. myvideo.de. is there a more general solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is unsovled since ages. The only halfway acceptable workaround (for Chrome/Chromium-users at least) is to install [Maximize Flash](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lljjmflmcnaigbhnheldbdbplkbhngnl) and then to open Chrome/Chromium-fullscreen-mode via `[F11]`.